# How to know the origin of an event in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Lets suppose:

I have an app installed in two devices, A and B.
This app listen to a person collection changes, as you can see:

```
   FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("people").addSnapshotListener((snapshots, e) -> {
        if (e != null || snapshots == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            if(dc == null){
                continue;
            }

            switch (dc.getType()) {
                case ADDED:
                    onDocumentAdded(dc.getDocument());
                    break;
                case MODIFIED:
                    onDocumentModified(dc.getDocument());
                    break;
                case REMOVED:
                    onDocumentRemoved(dc.getDocument());
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
```

When device A adds a new person to the people collection, device B will be notified about it, but device A as well.

In my case, I am implementing Firestore in a existing app and it already have a persistence logic.

In fact, whenever a new person is added by device A, I already have it stored in the app of device A, but I want to save it in device B as well.

However, as device A is notified too and I would save this person twice.

Some solutions I've been thinking:

- Storing an unique ID (UUID) on my local database and check if exists (but on Modified event it would not work);
- Defining a client ID (UUID) and send it. When I get the notification by the listener, I check if the client ID is the same I have defined locally.

I asking it because I do not know if already exists a way to handle with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If device A creates the document, and you have an active listener on the document created (or in this case, it's collection), you should find that `snapshots.getMetadata().isFromCache() == true` and the document added should also have a similar trait - `dc.getDocument().getMetadata().isFromCache() == true`.

However, this is not entirely fool-proof, as documents that have Field Transforms such as `serverTimestamp()` may only fire the listener once they been accepted and resolved by Firestore.

An alternative is to simply add the new person to Firestore (without saving it locally first) and let the snapshot listeners handle persisting the data. As mentioned above, the listener will normally be fired locally while the data is being sent off to your actual Firestore database.

Comment: I will accept  this as the answer, because in my case, I do not use documents with Field Transforms, so I don't do anything if the document given by the listener is from cache. It worked the way I wanted to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I needed this, I've kept a list of the document IDs that the local client has written in local storage, and then check the snapshots in the listener against that list.

It's a bit of a brute force approach, but pretty simple to implement. And if you prune the IDs from the local list in the listener once you've gotten the update, the memory overhead is pretty minimal.